# regarding integrating R into Web-applications

Tags: java, r

I have been using R to perform statistical analysis. I would like to know how to integrate the R-based analysis into a Web-application. For instance, let user submit the data, and invoke R to perform related analysis on the back-end.

The possible Web-application will be written in Java. What confuses me is the integration process.

I am new to Web-application, so any suggestions, tutorials, and examples will be highly-appreciated.

Comment: +1 for the question for which I would also like an answer.  However it is true that you don't "show research effort" even though it is clear ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at RSS, Rweb, R Node, etc?

http://www.unt.edu/rss/Rinterface.htm

http://www.math.montana.edu/Rweb/

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#R-Web-Interfaces

http://www.decisionstats.com/r-node-and-other-web-interfaces-to-r/

http://sysbio.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/Rwui/

Answer (score 2):

To run R code inside Java, I recommend to use the [JRI library](http://stats.math.uni-augsburg.de/JRI/).
To get started with java web applications, you should read a tutorial such as Oracle's "[Get started with Web Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/WebApp.html)".